# Choosing Applications after search with left/right buttons not working anymore

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

When opening the applications window in Gnome 40 (Ubuntu 20.10) and typing some letters to search for an application, I can not choose the app with left/right buttons anymore.
The searchbar looses focus when I try to move to the side. When I type again the focus is on the searchbar and moving with the arrow keys moves inside of text.

Moving down chooses the other search options, but moving back up looses focus again.

I tried turning off all extensions. What else should I do to try to get the functionality back?

[image: When typing text]
[image: after pressing the right arrow key]

Comment: Probably you use 21.10, not 20.10? After disabling extensions, did you try loging out then back in to see whether it works again?

Comment: Yeah, even after loging out with all extensions off and logging back in the problem persists... Any idea what it could be?
(Yes 21.10)

Comment: Rereading, I wonder what you mean by left/right buttons? What do you do when you "try move to the side"? Provide very precise steps so someone else can reproduce and see whether it behaves the same.

Comment: I usually search for an application by entering the first couple of letters and then use the left/right arrow keys on my keyboard to select the one I need. Currently the application window looses focus when I press the left/right key instead of cycling through the applications. 
As seen on picture 1, where "Settings" is selected and picture 2 where nothing is selected after I pressed the right arrow key on my keyboard.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. For me it behaves as expected.